# Python - specify corpus from whose sentence to perform a function on?

Tags: python, nltk

I have imported all the books from the NLTK Book library, and I am just trying to figure out how to define a corpus then sentence to be printed.

For example, if I wanted to print sentence 1 of text 3, then sentence 2 of text 4

```
import nltk
from nltk.book import *
print(???)
print(???)
```

I've tried the below combinations, which do not work:

```
print(text3.sent1)
print(text4.sent2)

print(sent1.text3)
print(sent2.text4)

print(text3(sent1))
print(text4(sent2))
```

I am new to python, so it is likely a v. basic question, but I cannot seem to find the solution elsewhere.

Many thanks, in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to split the texts into lists of sentences first.

If you already have `text3` and `text4`:

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize

sents = sent_tokenize(text3)
print(sents[0])  # the first sentence in the list is at position 0

sents = sent_tokenize(text4)
print(sents[1])  # the second sentence in the list is at position 1

print(text3[0])  # prints the first word of text3
```

You seem to need both a NLTK tutorial and a python tutorial.  Luckily, [the NLTK book](http://www.nltk.org/book/) is both.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am actually working through the NLTK book - it is useful for people new to python and NLTK.

Comment: @LdnTky1985, why did you accept this answer? The advice to read some tutorials is good, but the code is incorrect and even raises an error.

Answer (score 0):

Simple example can be given as :

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize

# List of sentences
sentences = "This is first sentence. This is second sentence. Let's try to tokenize the sentences. how are you? I am doing good"

# define function
def sentence_tokenizer(sentences):

    sentence_tokenize_list = sent_tokenize(sentences)

    print "tokenized sentences are = ", sentence_tokenize_list
    return sentence_tokenize_list

# call function 
tokenized_sentences = sentence_tokenizer(sentences)
# print first sentence
print tokenized_sentences[0]
```

Hope this helps.